# How to assign space-containing values to variables in bash using eval

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I want to dynamically assign values to variables using `eval`.
The following dummy example works:

```
var_name="fruit"
var_value="orange"
eval $(echo $var_name=$var_value)
echo $fruit
orange
```

However, when the variable value contains spaces, `eval` returns an error, even if `$var_value` is put between double quotes:

```
var_name="fruit"
var_value="blue orange"
eval $(echo $var_name="$var_value")
bash: orange : command not found
```

Any way to circumvent this ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't use eval, use [`declare`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-declare)

```
$ declare "$var_name=$var_value"
$ echo "fruit: >$fruit<"
fruit: >blue orange<
```

Answer (score 12):

Don't use `eval` for this; use `declare`.

```
var_name="fruit"
var_value="blue orange"
declare "$var_name=$var_value"
```

Note that word-splitting is not an issue, because everything following the `=` is treated as the value by `declare`, not just the first word.

In `bash` 4.3, named references make this a little simpler.

```
$ declare -n var_name=fruit
$ var_name="blue orange"
$ echo $fruit
blue orange
```

You *can* make `eval` work, but you still shouldn't :) Using `eval` is a bad habit to get into.

```
$ eval "$(printf "%q=%q" "$var_name" "$var_value")"
```

Comment: Using `eval` _that way_ is wrong. You're expanding `$var_value` before passing it to `eval` which means it's going to be interpreted as shell code! (try for instance with `var_value="';:(){ :|:&};:'"`)

Comment: Good point; there are some strings you can't safely assign using `eval` (which is one reason I said you shouldn't use `eval`).

Comment: @chepner - I do not believe that is true. maybe it is, but not this one at least. parameter substitutions allow for conditional expansion, and so you can expand only safe values in most cases, I think. still, your primary problem for `$var_value` is one of quote inversion - assuming a safe value for `$var_name` *(which can be just as dangerous an assumption, really)*, then you should be enclosing the right-hand-side's double-quotes within single-quotes - not vice-versa.

Comment: I think I've fixed the `eval`, using `printf` and its `bash`-specific `%q` format. This is still not a recommendation to use `eval`, but I think it is safer than it was before. That fact that you need to go to this much effort to get it to work is proof that you should be using `declare` or named references instead.

Comment: Well, actually, in my opinion, named references are the problem. The best way to use it - in my experience - is like... `set -- a bunch of args; eval "process2 $(process1 "$@")"` where `process1` just prints quoted numbers like `"${1}" "${8}" "${138}"`. That's crazy simple - and as easy as `'"${'$((i=$i+1))'}" '` in most cases. *indexed* references make it safe, robust, and *fast*. Still - I upvoted.

Comment: Nice hack with `%q`. I always feed dirty for receiving rep for "don't do this" answers.

Answer (score 4):

A good way to work with `eval` is to replace it with `echo` for testing. `echo` and `eval` work the same (if we set aside the `\x` expansion done by some `echo` implementations like `bash`'s under some conditions).

Both commands join their arguments with one space in between. The difference is that `echo` *displays* the result while `eval` *evaluates*/*interprets* as shell code the result.

So, to see what shell code

```
eval $(echo $var_name=$var_value)
```

would evaluate, you can run:

```
$ echo $(echo $var_name=$var_value)
fruit=blue orange
```

That's not what you want, what you want is:

```
fruit=$var_value
```

Also, using `$(echo ...)` here doesn't make sense.

To output the above, you'd run:

```
$ echo "$var_name=\$var_value"
fruit=$var_value
```

So, to interpret it, that's simply:

```
eval "$var_name=\$var_value"
```

Note that it can also be used to set individual array elements:

```
var_name='myarray[23]'
var_value='something'
eval "$var_name=\$var_value"
```

As others have said, if you don't care your code being `bash` specific, you can use `declare` as:

```
declare "$var_name=$var_value"
```

However note that it has some side effects.

It limits the scope of the variable to the function where it's run in. So you can't use it for instance in things like:

```
setvar() {
  var_name=$1 var_value=$2
  declare "$var_name=$var_value"
}
setvar foo bar
```

Because that would declare a `foo` variable local to `setvar` so would be useless.

`bash-4.2` added a `-g` option for `declare` to declare a *global* variable, but that's not what we want either as our `setvar` would set a *global* var as opposed to that of the caller if the caller was a function, like in:

```
setvar() {
  var_name=$1 var_value=$2
  declare -g "$var_name=$var_value"
}
foo() {
  local myvar
  setvar myvar 'some value'
  echo "1: $myvar"
}
foo
echo "2: $myvar"
```

which would output:

```
1:
2: some value
```

Also, note that while `declare` is called `declare` (actually `bash` borrowed the concept from the Korn shell's `typeset` builtin), if the variable is already set, `declare` doesn't declare a new variable and the way the assignment is done depends on the type of the variable.

For instance:

```
varname=foo
varvalue='([PATH=1000]=something)'
declare "$varname=$varvalue"
```

will produce a different result (and potentially have nasty side effects) if `varname` was previously declared as a *scalar*, *array* or *associative array*.

Also note that `declare` is not any safer than `eval`, if the contents of `$varname` is not tightly controlled.

For instance, both `eval "$varname=\$varvalue"` and `declare "$varname=$varvalue"` would reboot the system if `$varname` contained `a[$(reboot)1]` for instance.

Comment: What's wrong with being bash specific? OP put the bash tag on the question, so he's using bash. Providing alternates is good, but I think telling someone not to use a feature of a shell because it's not portable is silly.

Comment: @Patrick, seen the smiley? Having said that, using portable syntax means less effort when you need to port your code to another system where `bash` is not available (or when you realise you need a better/faster shell). The `eval` syntax works in all Bourne-like shells and is POSIX so all systems will have a `sh` where that works. (that also means my answer applies to all shells, and sooner or later, as happens often here, you'll see a non-bash specific question closed as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: but what if `$var_name` contains tokens? ...like `;`?

Comment: @mikeserv, then it's not a variable name. If you can't trust its content, then you need to sanitize it with both `eval` and `declare` (think of `PATH`, `TMOUT`, `PS4`, `SECONDS`...).

Comment: but on the first pass its always a variable expansion and never a variable name until the second. in my answer i sanitize it with a parameter expansion, but if youre implying doing the sanitization in a subshell on the first pass, that could as well be done portably w/ `export`. i dont follow the parenthetical bit on the end though.

Comment: @mikeserv, what I'm saying is that if `varname` is meant to contain a variable name and `varvalue` is meant to contain a variable value (so any string), then `$varvalue` may contain a `;`, but `$varname` may not. If you don't have control over the content of `$varname` (but I can't think of a context where that makes sense) and you want to avoid it having nasty side effects, then you need to sanitize it anyway whether you use `eval` or `declare`.

Comment: i get that - but you always have control over expansions. one scenario where it *might* make sense would be parsing `set` or `export -p`- like splitting them with `IFS==`. in a situation like that you would *very likely* have a valid varname, but edge cases can wipe a disk. in any case - you had a good point about my post - i made a tiny update and must do better - but yours is completely fixed. also... unicycling?

Answer (score 1):

If you do:

```
eval "$name=\$val"
```

...and `$name` contains a `;` - or any of several other tokens the shell might interpret as delimiting a simple command - preceded by proper shell syntax, that will be executed.

```
name='echo hi;varname' val='be careful with eval'
eval "$name=\$val" && echo "$varname"
```

#### OUTPUT

```
hi
be careful with eval
```

It can sometimes be possible to separate the evaluation and execution of such statements, though. For example, `alias` can be used to pre-evaluate a command. In the following example the variable definition is saved to an `alias` that can only be successfully declared if the `$nm` variable it is evaluating contains no bytes that do not match ASCII alphanumerics or `_`.

```
LC_OLD=$LC_ALL LC_ALL=C
alias "${nm##*[!_A-Z0-9a-z]*}=_$nm=\$val" &&
eval "${nm##[0-9]*}" && unalias "$nm"
LC_ALL=$LC_OLD
```

`eval` is used here to handle invoking the new `alias` from a varname. But it is only called at all if the previous `alias` definition is successful, and while I know a lot of different implementations will accept a lot of different kinds of values for `alias` names, I haven't yet run into one that will accept a completely empty one.

The definition within the `alias` is for `_$nm`, however, and this is to ensure that no significant environment values are written over. I don't know of any noteworthy environment values beginning with a `_` and it is usually a safe bet for semi-private declaration.

Anyway, if the `alias` definition is successful it will declare an `alias` named for `$nm`'s value. And `eval` will only call that `alias` if also does not start with a number - else `eval` gets only a null argument. So if both conditions are met `eval` calls the alias and the variable definition saved in the alias is made, after which the new `alias` is promptly removed from the hash table.

Comment: `;` is not allowed in variable names. If you don't have control over the content of `$name`, then you need to sanitize it for `export`/`declare` as well. While `export` doesn't execute code, setting some variables like `PATH`, `PS4` and many of those at `info -f bash -n 'Bash Variables'` have equally dangerous side effects.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - of course it is not allowed, but, as before, its not a variable name on `eval`'s first pass - it is a variable expansion. As you said elsewhere, in that context it is very much allowed. Still the $PATH argument is a very good one - i made a small edit and will add some later.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - better late than never...?

Comment: In practice, `zsh`, `pdksh`, `mksh`, `yash` don't complain on `unset 'a;b'`.

Comment: You'll want `unset -v -- ...` as well.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - That's *very* useful information - I only came back to this because I was thinking on how to do it at least cost for my own - *purportedly* - portable project. Anyway, I just made another edit to offer a different option.

Comment: Try with `varname='a[\`echo rm -rf / >&2\`],a'` with `bash` for instance.

Comment: @StephaneChezales - I'd rather not. Forgot about backquotes - should filter for them too. Thanks again.

Comment: Still doesn't exclude invalid variables like `(rm -rf / 1)+a` or `a,b`, and can have nasty side effects like with `PATH=42,a` or execute arbitrary code like with `a='a[$(id >&2)]' varname='a,b'`

Comment: @StephaneChezales - What? How can it do any of those things? In the case a `)` or *don't know how to put a backquote in a comment* exists in `$varname` then the resulting arithmetic is op is `"$(($$=0))"` - which is a syntax error. I don't understand how any of those things can happen.

Comment: Sorry, `(rm -rf / 1)+a` is wrong since you strip the `)+a`. In the case of `a='b[$(id >&2)]' varname='a,b' bash -c ': "$((${varname%%*[\`\)]*}$$=0))"'`, you're evaluating `a,b1234=0` as an arithmetic expression and that `a` is recursively evaluated which is where you've got the code injection (that is why it's known (not as widely as one would like) that you mustn't use external data in arithmetic evaluations).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - I've never seen that comma thing before - and my next step is to look it up. In any case the test is now explicit in case I've missed anything else. Dang, man, you're good. I really appreciate it. My little project involves recursively building arrays based on evaluated names - that could have been bad.

Comment: Now, with the latest edit, you might as well do a `case $varname in ("" | *[!_[:alnum:]]* | [[:digit:]]*) invalid; esac` Or even `("" | [!_[:alnum:]])` since you're adding a `_` prefix anyway.

Comment: `,` is just the `,` operator. `+`, `-`.... would work as well.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - I was just thinking the same, but now I'm not so sure if I shouldn't go back to the other - I guess the comma is pretty cool. But, understanding it a little better, I think it might be down to those three. The `=` assignment shouldn't work after an add. Those should require a separate `$((  ))` statement of their own.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - but I guess that is a shell dependent thing and maybe the portable app focuses a little harder on what is than what should be, I guess.

Comment: Also note that the check for `[:alnum:]` only works in `yash`, `ksh93` and `zsh`. It only works in `bash` in single-byte locales, and in other shells in ASCII locales, so you may want to check for ASCII alnums only.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - it's stuff like this that makes me wish `-t` had stuck - and had a real meaning. It would have been pretty handy for the `bash` devs that exploit thing you found, too. Maybe I could use IFS and look for extra fields...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - hopefully you'll let me know if you can break it now?

Answer (score -1):

use dead quote ie. apstroph.
eval $(echo $var_name='$var_value')
it worked with me.

Answer (score -1):

First, [double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2086). `$var_name` should be quoted, for best habit.

In normal shell script, variables turn into values, which is called expansion.
When `eval` is in use, in addition to the normal phrase one expansion, variable are expanded *inside* `eval` also. This is what makes `eval` so powerful (not evil if used with care).

**Solution one:**

Suppress the expansion of `$var_value` outside `eval` by **single quotes**. `eval` takes one argument `fruit=$var_value`. Note that this is no different from `eval 'fruit=$var_value'` in plain text. Beware that the value in `var_name` should not contain any spaces. All three examples are the same, as long as they suppress the expansion. `$var_value` is treated as plain text.

```
var_name="fruit" ; var_value="blue orange" ; eval "$var_name"='$var_value' ; echo "$fruit"

var_name="fruit" ; var_value="blue orange" ; eval "$var_name"='$'var_value ; echo "$fruit"

var_name="fruit" ; var_value="blue orange" ; eval "$var_name"=\$var_value ; echo "$fruit"
```

**Solution two:**

Give `eval` the quotes. In these cases, both `$var_name` and `$var_value` get expanded outside `eval`. `eval` gets `fruit='blue orange'` or `fruit="blue orange"`.

```
var_name="fruit" ; var_value="blue orange" ; eval "$var_name"=\'"$var_value"\' ; echo "$fruit"

var_name="fruit" ; var_value="blue orange" ; eval "$var_name"=\""$var_value"\" ; echo "$fruit"

var_name="fruit" ; var_value="blue orange" ; eval "$var_name=\"$var_value\"" ; echo "$fruit"
```

Single quotes and double quotes make no different in the above case. But when it comes to indirect variables, it makes a different.

```
basket='$var_value' ; var_name="fruit" ; var_value="blue orange" ; eval "$var_name"=\'"$basket"\' ; echo "$fruit"
$var_value

basket='$var_value' ; var_name="fruit" ; var_value="blue orange" ; eval "$var_name"=\""$basket"\" ; echo "$fruit"
blue orange
```

---

In your example, the use of `echo` is not necessary.

`echo $var_name="$var_value"` expands to `fruit=blue orange`. The problem is this string is not quoted. `eval` takes two arguments, `fruit=blue` and `orange`, separately. To fix it, either suppress the expansion of `$var_value`, or give it the proper quotes.

```
var_name="fruit" ; var_value="blue orange" ; eval $(echo "$var_name"='$var_value') ; echo "$fruit"

var_name="fruit" ; var_value="blue orange" ; eval $(echo "$var_name"=\'"$var_value"\') ; echo "$fruit"
```

This use of `echo` is redundant. Try to avoid it as much as possible.

Comment: What's the point of `$(echo ...)` in that last part there? Also, consider what happens with solution two if `var_value` contains a single or double quotes.

Comment: `echo` is redundant, just for illustration purpose. If `var_value` contains quotes, the quotes should be properly escaped. `eval` is not expected to take arbitrary input. `eval` is powerful when we have whole control of the input, e.g. internal program. Arbitrary input must be sterilised.

Comment: `eval` is pretty the only solution when accessing indirect variables, e.g. var01 var02 var03, and need POSIX compliant.

Comment: And also the use of `getopt` cannot avoid `eval`.

Comment: Don't you think mentioning any limitations and requirements of the code you're showing might be useful for the reader? Like the one you just mentioned in the comment there. In any case, I can't really tell what that `$(echo ...)` is illustrating there. Usually, putting an `echo` in a command substitution is worse than useless, e.g. in that last one, it mangles the value if it contains whitespace other than single spaces (and simply escaping doesn't help).

Comment: Anyway, as long as the value to be set is in a variable (with a known name), you seem to already have a working solution in solution one, so I'm just wondering how useful the broken ones are.

Comment: what does `getopt` have to do with any of this?