# How to print the values of variables with incremented numbers using a loop in shell script?

Tags: shell-script

I have a Bash script where i have calculated many values and stored them in the variables which have a number for each row. For instance, i have a variable named as `TC_5` which calculates the value of 5th row of the input csv file. I have calculated all the values and stored in variables which have the naming convention of `TC_<Row_No>` so that for 200 rows i have values stored in:

```
TC_1
TC_2
.
.
TC_200
```

Now, i want to write a loop which could print the values of all these variables together to an external file instead of manually printing them. For this, i am using the while loop as follows:

```
i=0
while [ "$i" != 201 ]
do
    echo "TC_$i" >> Out
    i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

How can i modify the above code in such a way that the echo statement would print the variable `TC_<RowNo>` to the `Out` File?

Comment: Why not use `awk/sed`?

Comment: Do you hear about arrays?

Comment: Hello Guys, could you please provide your suggestions as answers? I don't want to do it strictly with while loop. Any other option which is faster and better would be appreciated. Of course i have heard about arrays :)

Answer (score 2):

Your current script stuck in an infinitive loop, because the condition `[ "$i" != 201 ]` was always true.

You must increase `$i` after each iteration and using [eval](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23111/38906) to print the content of `TC_<RowNo>` variable (but [it's not safe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155126/38906)):

```
i=1
while [ "$i" -ne 201 ]
do
    eval printf '%s\\n' "\${TC_$i}"
    i=$((i+1))
done >> "Out"
```

Note that `$i` started at `1`, the use of `-ne` for integer comparison and the redirection at the end of `while` loop.

Comment: Good point cuonglm. Actually i missed to put the increment statement in the above example. That is present in my main script. Thanks for your answer. I will try it and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way to do this sort of thing in bash is to use an array:

```
TC[1]=something
TC[2]=somethingelse
...
TC[200]=somethingstillelse

i=1
while ((i <= 200)); do
    echo "${TC[i]}" >> Out
    ((i++))
done
```

But if you really want to embed the indexes in plain variable names, you can use an indirect variable reference:

```
TC_1=something
TC_2=somethingelse
...
TC_200=somethingstillelse

i=1
while ((i <= 200)); do
    varname=TC_$i    # Need to store the variable name in a variable first
    echo "${!varname}" >> Out    # The ! (and braces) trigger indirect expansion
    ((i++))
done
```

Note that neither of these features are available in basic POSIX shells like dash. Make sure your script is running under bash, not a generic shell.

Answer (score -1):

I changed your `while` loop slightly and it worked for me:

```
i=1
while [ "$i" != 201 ]
do
    echo $TC_$i >> Out
    i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

Note the $ in front of `TC_$i` and the removal of the double quotes. (I included the modification cuonglm suggested for the starting value.)

(Using GNU bash in iTerm on a Mac running High Sierra.)

Comment: Really?  That doesn't work for me.   (Are you *sure* you're using bash?)

Comment: ~/CertificateTest/save 499> /bin/sh --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: No, `$TC_$i` would expand to the concatenation of the values of the  variables `TC_` and `i`.

Comment: And yet, it really did work for me on GNU bash...